# How can I auto increment an iSeries database column when inserting via SQL from several websites?

Tags: sql, coldfusion, ibm-midrange, uniqueidentifier, db2-400

Crazy question. I know. Here's the scenario:

My client has several ColdFusion websites that all hit the same library on the same iSeries database. Let's say, for argument's sake, the following SQL query can be run from any of these websites:

```
<cfquery datasource="myDS">
    INSERT INTO XQX.myTable
       (
        x_ID,
        x_Name,
        x_Phone
       )
    VALUES
       (
        #myId#,
        #Name#,
        #Phone#
       )
</cfquery>
```

(I know there's no CFQUERYPARAMs, etc., let's just assume for simplicity's sake that the above query is A-Ok)

I could generate the Id by querying the table prior to the insert to get the maximum value, then incrementing it, like so:

```
<cfquery name="qMaxId" datasource="myDS">
    SELECT MAX(x_Id) AS MaxId
    FROM XQX.myTable
</cfquery>

<cfset myId = qMaxId.MaxId + 1 />
```

But, I worry about two users hitting the table at the same exact time, and both getting the same "new" Id.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You're on an iSeries - are you running over DB2?

Comment: "DB2 for i" is _the_ database on the iSeries.  It is part of the operating system.  

Why is this question tagged "tsql"?  It seems to have drawn a SQL Server answer from @KM.

Answer (score 3):

Especially in a web context, you *should* be worried about concurrent users.  There are two inherent problems with attempting to generate the id with `MAX()` like this:

1. You don't 'synchronize' access, and two users end up with the same id.
2. You *do* 'synchronize' access, and you create a bottleneck for table inserts.

DB2 (which is standard on an iSeries, usually) has something called a [SEQUENCE](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/db2/rbafzcsequence.htm) which you could query to generate your ids.
I don't know anything about coldfusion, but something like this:

```
<cfquery name="qNextId" datasource="myDS"> 
    SELECT NEXTVAL FOR [sequencename] AS NextId 
    FROM Sysibm.Sysdummy1
</cfquery> 

<cfset myId = qNextId.NextId />
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the SEQUENCE noted by @X-Zero, the IBM DB2 admin can put an auto-incrementing column called an IDENTITY in the database.

```
create MYTABLE ...
(ID int 
    generated always as IDENTITY(Start with 1 
                                 Increment by 1)
...
```

Comment: Unfortuanately, I have a feeling that the OP needs the value of the id genereated in his application, to reference for further `INSERT`s in the transaction.  If you don't have a unique natural key available, a data-change-table-reference should be used.  Since having the table manage its own ids is usually a good idea, can you supply the necessary retrieval syntax for the OP to use?

Comment: Right, so after doing an INSERT INTO, one would test SQLSTATE, and if 'normal', one would use VALUES IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL() INTO :generatedID;     http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/db2/rbafzscaidentity.htm

Comment: I'm a little twitchy about that function, given that it may not be the id you expect - say, if the 'table' you're inserting into is actually a view, with `INSTEAD OF` triggers to several tables.

Comment: I am at v5.4 and cannot test it, but at v6.1 I'd use a data change table reference.  select identity_val_local(), ... from (insert into ...))  http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v6r1m0/topic/db2/rbafztabref.htm    I am not suggesting that IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL() is the best solution, only one possible solution.  I wish the OP would come back and add to the discussion.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a Sequence object. For example

```
CREATE SEQUENCE XQX.mySeqObj
    as {numeric-datatype}
```

The data type can be SMALLINT, INTEGER, BIGINT, DECIMAL, or NUMERIC, with scale of zero (ie. no decimal places). A data area is created to store the value.

You can then use a `NEXT VALUE FOR` expression to retrieve and increment the Sequence, as in

```
INSERT INTO XQX.myTable
   (
    x_ID,
    x_Name,
    x_Phone
   )
VALUES
   (
    NEXT VALUE FOR XQX.mySeqObj,
    #Name#,
    #Phone#
   )
```

If you wish to know the prior value assigned within the current session you can use the expression `PREVIOUS VALUE FOR mySeqObj`, but naturally, only after you have used a `NEXT VALUE` expression within your session.